# ion-segment not refreshing with I click on tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a simple page with "Homes" and "sales data" in a ion-segment.

- The Homes data is refreshed with I click on the Data/Homes segment. Back
  and forth work fine.
- When I click on another tab and come back to the Home tab the Home
  segment is not refreshed with current or new home data.

  ```
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="currentsegment" color="primary">
    <ion-segment-button value="Homes" (ionSelect)="changeTab('Homes')">
      Homes
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="Data" (ionSelect)="changeTab('Data')">
      Data
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  ```

anyone have a fix for this issue? Strange caching.

Comment: can you add the content of the ts part?

Answer (score 0):

Aha so I suppose you have a Tabs Layout page.

In your ts you can bind to the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle. This will fire, well, when you enter the view so basically every time you come back to the page.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  if(this.currentsegment == 'Homes') {
    this.functionThatSetsMyHomeData();
  }
}
```